# How to use another field in rails validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I'm not trying to do a conditional validation, instead I just want to use other fields to look up hashes for example:

`validates :type, presence: true, inclusion: { in: TYPES[self.category]}`

But this generates this error:

```
undefined method `category'
```

Which I think is because `self` doesn't exist yet. Is that correct? Any thoughts on how I might approach this?

Exact Code:

```
 class Rate < ActiveRecord::Base                                

      RISK_TYPES = {c_and_f: ('a'..'e').to_a.map(&:to_sym),                                                                                        
                    m:       ('a'..'e').to_a.map(&:to_sym),                                                                                        
                    l_and_p:  ('a'..'e').to_a.map(&:to_sym),                                                                                        
                    o:            ('a'..'e').to_a.map(&:to_sym)}                                                                                        

    validates :risk_type, presence: true, inclusion: { in: lambda{|Rate| RISK_TYPES[Rate.category]}}                                       
  end
```

Comment: I think it has something to do with the lambda, but I'm probably wrong.  Have you tried throwing that into a custom method?  `def category_exists?  errors.add(:base, "Category must exist") unless  ThisClass.category.include(self.category)  end`

or something like that (not 100% on what you're trying to do)

Comment: `self` isn't the object under validation, but rather the validation context itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
validates :risk_type, presence: true, inclusion: { in: lambda{|rate| TYPES[rate.category]}}
```

Comment: I get `formal argument cannot be a constant (SyntaxError)`

Comment: change the lambda argument from `Rate` to `rate`.

Answer (score 1):

You can validates like this:

```
validates :type, presence: true, inclusion: %w(category)
```

and add new method as:

```
def self.category
   where type: 'category'
end
```